# Creating a library as a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have a question related to creating a library for react (component library). Is there any "how to" or "best practices" or even a boilerplate to start? (something like create-react-app but for a library)

Comment: Curiously enough - I've just been working on this. 

The best place to start - is webpack, and understanding about how it bundles in to the dist folder. If you're iterested - here's my github for a react typescript component (it's much simpler if you're not using typescript). https://github.com/dwjohnston/react-rgba-color-picker

Comment: It might be worth checking out [microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Nwb](https://github.com/insin/nwb), Here is a link teaching you how to use it as well [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@efreyreg/create-react-component-libraries-with-storybook-and-styled-jsx-8999f423f06b). It's a pretty sweet project, I used it in the past.

Comment: thanks, indeed it's very good. I'll check it today.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have further questions don't hesitate to ask.